# How to use case on group by result in Oracle-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, case

I have a table containing the below column

```
person_id Person_Name Telephone_No City Email_Id Insert_TS
```

and there are certain other column like Alternate_name etc.
In this table, whenever there is any update in any of the particular a row is  inserted . For example

```
P01 Radhe 0112311231 Bia b@b.com 09-NOV-2012 15:24:38 
P01 Radhe Null  Bia    a@b.com  30-APR-2014 21:26:51 
P02 Shayam 456897845 Albi s@b.com 30-APR-2014 14:36:03
P03 Radha Null xyz   s1@b.com 31-APR-2014 14:36:03
```

Means, few record contains null in telephone  field but all other fields have data

I want to display person_id Person_Name Telephone_No City Email_Id columns such that if there is any row containing telephone_no value not null corresponding to one person_id then the latest record of that should be displayed 
else
latest record of the person should be displayed

to summarize display unique person_id with latest telephone_no for those person which does not have telephone_no latest record should be displayed.

I tried this way :

Get the unique person_id with latest telephone_no --  A
Get all unique person_id  with latest record --- B

display the data as (B-A) + A .

But that is taking too much time and that does not seems to be efficient .
Please suggest a query to fetch the records faster

Other possible way could be using the case statement on group by result like grouping the values by Person_id if there is any telephone_no in each group display the one with latest value otherwise display the latest entry from group

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be sufficient to always show the last row for each person? Assuming person_id, Insert_TS is unique:

```
select person_id, max(Insert_TS)
from T
group by person_id
```

then join that with the table to get all info.

For recent versions of oracle you can use row_number() as in

```
select ... 
from (
    select ..., row_number() over (partition by person_id
                                   order by Insert_TS desc) as rn
) as x
where rn = 1;
```

I'm not sure I fully understand but here's a try. I get errors from SQLFiddle for Oracle, and I don't have access to Oracle my self so the following is tested on DB2 V10.5. I simplified a bit by removing a couple of columns. Furthermore the timestamps are different than yours:

```
with tmp as (select PERSON_ID, PERSON_NAME, TELEPHONE_NO, INSERT_TS
            ,row_number() over (partition by person_id 
                                order by insert_ts desc) as rn 
            from t) 
select * from tmp x 
where rn = (
    select coalesce(min(rn),1) 
    from tmp y 
    where x.person_id = y.person_id 
      and y.TELEPHONE_NO is not null
);

PERSON_ID PERSON_NAME TELEPHONE_NO    INSERT_TS                  RN                  
--------- ----------- --------------- -------------------------- --------------------
P01       Radhe       011231123109    2012-05-22-14.27.35.037579                    2
P02       Shayam      456897845       2014-05-22-14.27.35.037579                    1
P03       Radha       -               2014-06-22-14.27.35.037579                    1

3 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying 
The latest row may not contain the information inserted in the previous rows for the same person id .
For example , if there is change in email id and not telephone no then the latest row may not contain details about telephone no

Comment: Ok, so the last non null value for each column would be sufficient?

Comment: no as there are few person for whom there is no value for telephone no